# Image upload through API using php curl not working

Tags: php, image, curl, file-upload

I am trying to upload the image to database using api

---

```php
$curl = curl_init();    
 $headers = array("Content-Type: multipart/form-data",);     
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);     
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
 CURLOPT_URL => 'api url',
 CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
 CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
 CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
 CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
 CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
 CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
 CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
 CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array('file'=> new CURLFILE($_FILES['cfile']['tmp_name'])),
));     
 
$response = curl_exec($curl);     
 
curl_close($curl);     
echo $response;
```

In this code image is not getting store as expected CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array('file'=> new CURLFILE($_FILES['cfile']['tmp_name']))